# Why does this code not render the correct thing?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have this code for redirecting the user to different subpages in Python flask:

```py
@app.route('/')
def main():
    return render_template('interface.html')

@app.route('/#ordergrade/')
def ordergrade():
    return sort.orderbygrade(True, False).to_html()
```

`interface.html` has this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Options</h1>
    <p>Click on the buttons below to be redirected to a web page.</p>
    <button onclick="window.location.hash='#ordergrade/'">1</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.hash='#orderuniversity/'">2</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.hash='#showopts/'">3</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.hash='#delete/'">4</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.hash='#infnum/'">5</button>
    <button onclick="window.location.hash='#supnum/'">6</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

When clicking the first button, I get correctly redirected to the `/#ordergrade` page, but only `interface.html` is rendered. Why does that happen?

Everything seems to go correctly, except that nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`fragment`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_fragment) of a URL (the part after the `#`) is not sent to the server, so when you visit the path `/#ordergrade/` the server only sees `/`.

If you want a `#` in the URL, you'll need to encode it using [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding), E.g.,

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index_view():
    # Here, `%23` represents "#"
    return '<a href="/%23test/">test</a>'

@app.route("/#test/")
def test_view():
    return "worked!"
```

It's also possible to handle on the client, have a look at the browser/javascript [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event, or consider using a frontend javascript framework that includes a routing solution.